# How to get the Pi to recognize numbers and letters from images

Tags: raspicam

I would like to start a project that will take a picture of the license plate of a vehicle and then take all the digits and record them. Is there a way to have the Pi recognize the digits?

Comment: Please check those questions/answers https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=ocr to get you started on the topic. Ideally it would help you to narrow down your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at computer vision and the OpenCV library. To put it quickly, this problem has been solved before, and all you need to do is to google "recognizing numbers with opencv" to find tutorials.

[PyImageSearch is always a good resource for OpenCV.](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/)

[There are also many examples on YouTube. This is an example with license plates.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmDiZGx5mqU)

OpenCV is one of the most-used computer vision libraries available for Linux. And yes, it does compile on the Raspberry Pi.

Speaking of which, this is much more a generic Linux question than a Raspberry Pi question.

Comment: The reason why I asked it on here was because last time I tried, I remember seeing some compatibility issues. I wanted to get an answer from some people having used it on the rpi before.